# Netbeans PHP syntax highlight in template file

Tags: php, netbeans, savant3

I'm using netbeans 7.4 for my PHP web application which is based on [Savant3](http://phpsavant.com/) templating system.

However, when I put PHP code inside `.tpl` file, it is not considered as inline PHP code. 
It displays error saying `"Unexpected character(s) ? found Unexpected token LESS found"` wherever I put PHP opening tag (). And in meantime, it does not highlight the PHP code inside html attribute. Both these errors are highlighted in my uploaded image.

[image]

How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem using netbeans 8.0

Comment: Well recently I found out that netbeans does not support Savant3. So the only option is, make .php files(even for templates) instead of .tpl files.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files

In the `File Extension` dropdown choose `tpl`

In the `Associate File Type (MIME)` dropdown choose `text/x-php5`

Comment: theres a default plugin in netbeans 8.1 called PHP Smarty Framework, But it is not working as per expectations. For eg. PHP is considered as string in it and there is no syntax highlighting in PHP. and if you comment any html portion instead of `<!-- xyz -->` it comments like `{* xyz *}` which is worse. But your trick worked. Thanx.. +1...