# Netbeans: Syntax Highlighting -- multiple languages per file

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting

The majority of the pages I author contain both HTML and PHP. It would appear that in Netbeans you can have syntax highlighting for one or the other by setting the associated file types.

Coming from Notepad++, I've always taken for granted the fact that I could use php, css, html, javascript all in one file and retain syntax highlighting for all of them.

Is this possible in Netbeans?

Comment: Do the files you're working on have a .php file extension?

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401413/netbeans-php-syntax-highlight-in-template-file

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is that Netbeans DOES support multiple language, but it will only get it right if there's something hinting at the "inner" language. When I exit PHP with `?>` NetBeans tends to format what comes before the next `<?php` as HTML automatically. Not sure if that is working for you. Maybe you were trying to get highlighting in a string like `$output = "<some><html";`. I think you can imagine why that second one wouldn't work.

For JS, for example, it seems to look for the `<script type="text/javascript">`, and stuff inside gets the JS highlighting even if the file type is PHP.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161818/netbeans-php-javascript-highlighting/55009605#55009605) has a great solution for "tricking" Netbeans into rendering your JS output by PHP into being formatted, even when your code doesn't have a `<script type="text/javascript">` tag.